# How to convert Map entries into list of pair in elixir

Tags: elixir

I have one map which I need to convert into a map like below.

```
Input = %{DateFrom: "2020-08-05", DateTo: "2020-08-08", TransactionId: "1"}
Output = [ {"DateFrom", "2020-08-05"}, {"DateTo", "2020-08-08"}, {"TransactionId", "1"}]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This would not even compile, raising `MatchError`. When posting questions here you **must** validate you provide the correct input and show some effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension.

```
for {k, v} <- input, into: [], do: {"#{k}", "#{v}"}
```

https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/basics/comprehensions/#using-into

Also, you must keep your variable names lowercase, in erlang variables start with a capital letter.

Comment: Its output will be like [DateFrom: "2020-08-05", DateTo: "2020-08-08", TransactionId: "1"]

Comment: I've made an update, previous output was a keyword list, now it's a list with tuples

Answer (score -1):

I find my answer using below line.

```
Input |> Enum.map(fn {k, v} ->  {"#{k}","#{v}"} end)
```

[image]

Comment: This would not even compile, raising `Protocol.UndefinedError`. Also, instead of publishing your own answer, you should accept the one by @Mike that is technically identical.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I don't know why you feel it will not compile, please check the screenshot where I have ran it and the output is exactly what iI needed. Let me know what's wrong with my solution.

Comment: [tag:elixir] is case sensitive.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I know. but how does it related to my answer? If all good then Please press "This answer is useful"